# Laravel Custom Response Message For Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I speak to my laravel server through endpoints. I do not use Laravel View so I have no access to its session.

When a required request comes in, I need to return a response ie`401` etc per params? Possible?

`php artisan make:request FooBar`

Inside `FooBar`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'subtitle' => 'required|max:255',
        'title'    => 'required|max:255',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'title.required' => abort(401, sorry),
        // and others...
    ];
}
```

If I should use a string message instead of `abort()` laravel redirects without a response, I use postman and I see status 200. How to achieve what I want? I want to customise each required param with a response.

Comment: This is not possible using FromRequest. You may create a custom validator in your controller and then loop through the errors and respond accordingly based on the fields.

Comment: @Sandeesh Oh, never knew that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. Close to what you want, but you can't check for specific rule error. Can only check if a field failed the validation.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'subtitle' => 'required|max:255',
    'title'    => 'required|max:255',
]);

$errors = $validator->errors();

if ($errors->has('title')) {
    abort(401, 'sorry');
}
```

Comment: @Sylar depends on how you want to handle the validation failure. The errors array would contain the field name and message for all the failed rules. So if you want to abort for a particular field, then you need to use `has` to check if that field has failed.

Comment: But if `title` is present, you want to abort. I dont want to abort. Only abort if title not present

Comment: @Sylar this is the error array. It contains the field names of items which are not present in the input. So don't get confused. So if title is present in the errors array, it means it was not provided as the input.

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Understood. Thanks